# Seeding admin database Role not adding

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I am having some issues with getting my admin user have an admin role. Once I create a user and it succeeds I tried adding the admin role with AddToRoleAsync. But I am not sure why it's not being added. I then tried to have a check so that if the admin has no admin role it would add it. It looks like the command executes but I don't see it added to the database.

This is my code:

```
public async Task CreateAdmin()
{
       // Add roles
       string[] roles = new string[] {"Administrator", "User"};
       foreach(string role in roles)
       {
           bool result = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role);
           if(!result)
           {
               await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
           }
       }

       // Add admin user
       if (!_context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "Admin"))
       {
           var user = new Users
           {
               Email="admin@admin.com",
               NormalizedEmail="ADMIN@ADMIN.COM",
               UserName="admin@admin.com",
               NormalizedUserName="ADMIN",
               EmailConfirmed = true,
           };
           var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Password123");
       }

       var adminuser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("admin@admin.com");
       bool flag = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(adminuser, "Administrator");
       if(!flag)
       {
           var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Administrator");
           await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminuser, "Administrator");
            }
   }
```

If you want the full DbIntilizer or more code let me know.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Edit
Reworked it to follow this
http://www.locktar.nl/programming/net-core/seed-database-users-roles-dotnet-core-2-0-ef/
and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i do it.

```
public async Task InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            // Create DB
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

            // Add roles
            var roleManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole<long>>>();
            if (!roleManager.Roles.Any())
            {
                foreach (var role in Config.GetTestRolls())
                {
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                }
            }

            // Add users
            var userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            if (userManager.Users.Any()) return;
            foreach (var user in Config.GetTestUsers())
            {
                await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Password123!");
            }

            // find first user add to first role (hack) 
            var adminUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Config.GetTestUsers().FirstOrDefault()?.Email);
            if (adminUser != null)
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser, Config.GetTestRolls().FirstOrDefault()?.Name);
            }


        }
```

Code ripped from my GitHub Project found [here](https://github.com/LindaLawton/DotNetCoreSamples/tree/master/IdentityTest)

Comment: Thanks yours is a bit better than the link that I found. I will use this instead.